# Running a Windows keytab without domain admin privileges

Tags: windows, active-directory, privileges, keytab

within a java application we use a Windows keytab file which is mapping a principal to an AD-useraccount. This keytab was created on one of our domaincontrollers by a domainadmin. For security reasons now we want to reduce number of domainadmins and withdraw domain admin privileges from some accounts. the account which created our working keytab is also affected. i am unsure, i dont really know if our keytab will still work if original creator is not an domainadmin any more or is the keytab just independent from original creator.
I would be glad to hear your opinion to this topic.

Thank you,
Hans

I expect keytab will work, but iam not sure. I can not test it, we only have one system of this kind.

Comment: For all interested people: My Service is still working, even domain privileges of keytab creator are revoked.